# Как очистить удаленный git репозиторий

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

Как можно очистить удалённый репозиторий на bitbucket или github?

Прошу заметить, что с простым вариантом типа `git push --force origin master`  старые коммиты остаются в недрах репозитория (или я что-то не понимаю?), а хотелось бы почистить полностью, избавившись от старых (ну или окончательно удалить хотя бы конкретные).

Comment: Ну может быть остаются и что? Garbage collector их когда-нибудь приберёт.

Comment: Пересоздайте репозиторий целиком. Но вообще там, на сервере, должен раз в сутки хотя бы запускаться процесс `git gc`.

Comment: Смущает, например, то, что такие подвешенные коммины, влияют на contributions и многие другие показатели, причём, судя по срокам, они там похоже никогда (или почти никогда?) не чистятся...